# What happens when we call cpu().data.numpy() on a PyTorch tensor?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I am working on a project and need to pass the data in loss tensor to a plotting library.

What happens when I perform this call -> `loss.cpu().data.numpy()`

Is there a risk of detaching the tensor from the computation graph?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`.cpu()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.cpu) copies the tensor to the CPU, but if it is already on the CPU nothing changes.

[`.numpy()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.numpy) creates a NumPy array from the tensor. The tensor and the array share the underlying memory, therefore if the NumPy array is modified in-place, the changes will be reflected in the original tensor. If you plan to make in-place modifications to the NumPy array, you should generally create a copy of it. In the case where `loss` was on the GPU, `loss.cpu()` already creates a copy, hence the in-place modifications would only affect the intermediate CPU tensor, which you aren't using.

> Is there a risk of detaching the tensor from the computation graph?

No, the original tensor `loss` is not affected by this in regards to the computational graph.